# MongoParseError connecting to serverless Atlas DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, serverless, mongodb-atlas

I'm running a Node/Express/Mongoose App and when I try to connect it to a "Serverless" mongodb atlas database, I get the error

`` MongoParseError: Text record must only set `authSource` or `replicaSet` at QueryReqWrap.callback (/home/XXX/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:111:13) ``

And in the code when I run a query against a "User" model, I get

`` UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) (node:32601) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. ``

None of which show when I try a "free" regular version of the database (changing the connection URI obviously).

I'm using mongoose 5.13.7 and mongodb 4.1.0. My connection string is "mongodb+srv://user:password@serverlessinstance0.7eg4b.mongodb.net/db?retryWrites=true&w=majority&useMongoClient=true"

Any hints?

Comment: What does the TXT record of the cluster look like?

Comment: It's "authSource=admin&replicaSet=atlas-4qhb1z-shard-0"

Comment: what version of node.js driver is this using?  You must use at least version 4.1.0 to connect to Serverless  see https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/#minimum-driver-versions-for-serverless-instances

Comment: added packages and connection string info

Answer (score 0):

I have tried setting up two services with a serverless instance: 1. An [etherpad](https://etherpad.org/) instance, 2. a [strapi](https://strapi.io/) backend.

In both approaches I got stuck at this exact error. With a shared cluster both things worked fine. MongoDB also says that the NodeJS 3.7 driver support for serverless instances is coming soon. It seems that we'll just have to wait a bit for the drivers to get support and be patient :)

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the comment to the original question, you should use the node driver with version at least 4.1