# Connecting to mongodb atlas I get load balancer error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm receiving the following error in mongodb:

`MongoParseError: Load balancer mode requires driver version 4+`

However, in my case cannot upgrade to a version greater than 4. Is there any way I can turn off the load balancer mode for my serverless database on mongodb atlas?

Answer (score 0):

no, LB mode requires a driver that is aware of it. See some details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68658224/mongoparseerror-connecting-to-serverless-atlas-db/69454192#69454192)